# UIPopoverController does not close

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I have a normal UIPopoverController which is made in this way:

```
-(IBAction)btKBIs_click:(id)sender
{

if(kbiPopOver != NULL)
    [kbiPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

KBIViewController *kbiViewController = [[KBIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"KBIViewController" bundle:nil CurrentUser:currentUser];
kbiViewController.currentStatus = FIRST;
kbiViewController.firstlist = [currentUser getDescriptions];
kbiViewController.mapViewController =self;


UINavigationController* kbiNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:kbiViewController];

kbiPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:kbiNavController];
kbiPopOver.delegate = self;

kbiViewController.kbiPopOver = kbiPopOver;

[kbiPopOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:true];

}
```

Inside the class KBIViewController I'm calling:

```
    [self.kbiPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    [self.kbiPopOver.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:self.kbiPopOver];
```

To dismiss it but it does not work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the `<UIPopOverControllerDelegate>` in your class interface and did you implement the `– popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` method? Just call the `dismissPopoverAnimated:` explicitly in your code or in the delgate method, when you tap outside the popover. Remove that `[self.kbiPopOver.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:self.kbiPopOver];` from your code.

Comment: when user tap over the screen it dismiss, i want it dismiss when it tap on the view also ... i mean i want it dismiss when i need it.

Comment: i didn't implement popoverControllerDidDismissPopover should i ?

Comment: i want just close the window of the KBIViewController , i did         [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  but dose not work ...

Comment: The popover must be dismissed with (the name says it) `dismissPopoverAnimated`. Are you using ARC with this project? If not, you must release the view controller and the navigation controller after adding them.

Comment: i did         [self.kbiPopOver release];
        [self.navigationController release];
 and it dose not close

Comment: Can you put the whole class (.h and .m) on some site like pastebin.com?